# How to measure the word weight using doc2vec vector

Tags: python, algorithm, word-embedding, doc2vec

I'm using the word2vec algorithm to detect the most important words in a document, my question is about how to compute the weight of an important word using the vector obtained from doc2vec, my code is like that:

```
model = Doc2Vec.load(fname)
word=["suddenly"]
vectors=model.infer_vector(word)
```

thank you for your consideration.

Comment: First you'll need to define what you mean by "important" and "weight".

Comment: weight: mean its degree of importance, my application is to detect topics for each block of text (topics means "important words")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you can find the vector `R` corresponding to an entire document, using doc2vec. Let's also assume that using word2vec, you can find the vector `v` corresponding to any word `w` as well. And finally, let's assume that `R` and `v` are in the *same* N-dimensional space.

Assuming all this, you may then utilize plain old vector arithmetic to find out some correlations between `R` and `v`.

For starters, you can normalize `v`. Normalizing, after all, is just dividing each dimension with the magnitude of `v`. (i.e. `|v|`) Let's call the normalized version of `v` as `v_normal`.

Then, you may project `v_normal` onto the line represented by the vector `R`. That projection operation is just finding the dot product of `v_normal` and `R`, right? Let's call that scalar result of the dot product as `len_projection`. Well, you can consider `len_projection / |v_normal|` as an indication of how *parallel* the context of the word is to that of the overall document. In fact, considering just `len_projection` is enough, because in this case, as `v_normal` is normalized, `|v_normal| == 1`.

Now, you may apply this procedure to all words in the document, and consider the words that lead to greatest `len_projection` values as the most significant words of that document.

Note that this method may end up finding frequently-used words like *"I"*, or *"and"* as the most important words in a document, as such words appear in many different contexts. If that is an issue you would want to remedy, you may want do a post-processing step to filter such common words.

I sort of thought of this method on the spot here, and I am not sure whether this approach has any scientific backing. But, it may make sense, if you think about how most vector embeddings for words work. Word vectors are usually trained to represent the *context* in which a word is used. Thinking in terms of vector arithmetic, projecting the vector onto a line may reveal how parallel the context of that word `w` is, to the overall context represented by that line.

Last but not least, as I have worked only with word2vec before, I am not sure if doc2vec and word2vec data can be used adjointly like I mentioned above. As I stated in the first paragraph of my answer, it is really critical that `R` and `v` has to be in the *same* N-dimensional space.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I want something like the score of the word in a document because I can apply your proposed method because infer_vector method results an unnormalized vector :/, and i don't know how to resolve that ...

Comment: @mourchidyoussef  I edited my answer to be a bit more detailed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using `infer_vector()`, none of the words provided has any more 'weight' or 'importance'.

The process of inference tries to incrementally make a doc-vector that's generally pretty good at predicting all of the provided words, and every word is (in turn) an equally important target of the process.

Separately: inference rarely works well for tiny examples, like texts of just one or a few words. And inference usually works better when providing non-default values for its optional parameters. For example, instead of the default `steps=5`, a value of 20, 100, or more may be helpful, especially with smaller texts. Instead of the default starting `alpha=0.1`, a value of 0.025 (similar to the training default) often helps.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I want something like the score of the word in a document

Comment: What do you mean 'score of word in a document'?